# tm Corpus: tm_map function does not change the corpus

Tags: r, tm

I am new to the tm package in R. I am trying to create a document-term matrix with the `tm_map` function, but apparently the function passed to `tm_map(Corpus, function, lazy=TRUE)` is not applied to the corpus. Concretely, the documents are not converted to lower case. R Studio does not show any errors or warnings.
Did I mess up anything here? Could this be some enconding issue?

```
library(tm)
setwd("...")

filenames <- list.files(getwd(), pattern="*.txt")
files <- lapply(filenames, readLines)

docs <- Corpus(VectorSource(files))
writeLines(as.character(docs[[30]]))

docs <- tm_map(docs, function(x) iconv(enc2utf8(x$content), sub = ""), lazy=TRUE)

#to lower case
docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(tolower), lazy=TRUE)
writeLines(as.character(docs[[30]]))
```

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple fix.  Move your code for converting to lower case before iconv(...).

This works:

```
library(tm)
setwd("")

# Read in Files
filenames <- list.files(getwd(), pattern="*.txt")
files <- lapply(filenames, readLines)
docs <- Corpus(VectorSource(files))
writeLines(as.character(docs[[30]]))

# Lower Case
docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(tolower), lazy=TRUE)

# Convert
docs <- tm_map(docs, function(x) iconv(enc2utf8(x$content), sub = ""))
writeLines(as.character(docs[[30]]))
```